# PyQT5 drag and drop with internal move between two QListWidgets

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm looking for drag/drop functionality from list 1 into
list 2 and I also want drag/drop functionality for the items internally in
list 2. I cannot find a built in method to do both of these as requested. Thank you.

[image]

Here is my code. Thank you!

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.listWidget1 = QListWidget(self)
        self.listWidget1.addItems(['red', 'green', 'blue'])
        self.listWidget1.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)

        self.listWidget2 = QListWidget(self)
        self.listWidget2.addItems(['black', 'silver', 'grey'])
        self.listWidget2.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.listWidget2.setAcceptDrops(True)

        hbox.addWidget(self.listWidget1)
        hbox.addWidget(self.listWidget2)

        self.setLayout(hbox)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 250)
        self.show()


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the DragDropMode depending on the source of the event.

```
class List(QListWidget):

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.source() is self:
            self.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        else:
            self.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
        super().dragEnterEvent(event)
```

And use the subclass instead:

```
self.listWidget2 = List(self)
```

Comment: The solution was sub classing. I was expecting the solution to be a simple combination of just using the QAbstractItemView between the two lists but that was not the case. Thank you.